# Parent component function not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call from CompB  which is checking "if fullscreen" then call "additionalContent" which is basically then calling CompA "additionalcontent" which indeed then call Button component

but in this case, i am getting console log "AdditionalContentComp called" from CompB but no console log "additional content from CompA" ( which is basically not calling my Button component"

any help on where am i going wrong.

Folder Structure

```
src
  - Button.js
  - CompA.js
  - folderb
       - CompB.js
```

CompA.js

```
const CompA = (props) => {
  const [isContent] =true
  const additionalContent =
    () =>
      isContent
        ? (props) => <> {console.log("additional content from CompA")}<Button {...props} /></>
        : null
   return isContent ? (
   < CompB
     additionalContent={additionalContent}
   >
    {<CompC/>}
   ) : <CompD/>
}
export default CompA
```

CompB.js

```
const CompB = forwardRef({additionalContent = null}, forwardRef) => {
    const AdditionalContentComp =
      () =>
        fullscreen //value true
          ? additionalContent &&
            console.log('AdditionalContentComp called')
          : null
   return(
    <>
     {fullscreen && (
          <AdditionalContentComp
            ref={buttonref}
            varA={stateA}
          />
     )}
    </>
   )
}

export default CompB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [isContent] =true
```

is not probably what you want. Either you missed the `useState`, in that case, you want

```
const [isContent, setIsContent] = useState(true)
```

Or you just want to set `isContent` to `true`, like

```
const isContent = true
```

With `const [isContent] =true`, `isContent` is being set to `undefined`, which evaluates is a falsey value and so your log is never executed. Ideally, it should be throwing an error saying `true is not iterable`, so we're missing something here. If you must use the square bracket notation, make the right side an array like:

```
const [isContent] = [true]
```

Comment: isContent value i have given here true because its coming internally and didnt want to post the whole code for it. so set as true for this example

Comment: your isContent evaluates to false. from the code you have posted, this is the only way it can be false. it'd be great if you can add a reproducible example

Comment: found the mistake. it was not in this part of code. 
thank you for your time.